# Reading binary File into Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, binaryfiles, binary-data

I have a set of file that each contain a specific Record in `Marc21` binary format. I would like to ingest the set of files as an RDD, where each element would be a record object as binary data. Later on I will use a `Marc` library to convert the object into `Java Object` for further processing.

As of now, I am puzzled as to how i can read a binary file.

I have seen the following function:

```
binaryRecord(path: string, recordLength: int, conf)
```

However, it assume that it is a file with multiple records of the same length. My records will definitively be of different sizes. Beside each one is on a separate file.

Is there a way to get around that ? How can I for each file, give a length ? Would the only way only be calculating the length of my file and then reading the records ?

The other solution I see obviously would be to read the record in Java format and serialized that into whatever format is comfortable ingesting.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried sc.binaryFiles() from spark?

Here is the link to documentation
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#binaryFiles(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: At this point i am not using HDFS at all. I am working local without HDFS. In the future i know that I will read from Kafka. In other things will be ingested in Kafka and Spark will consume from it. But right now i just want to make some test. Can it work without HDFS ?

Comment: Yes. sc.binaryFiles("file:///path/to/local/file") should work.

Comment: Thx yes I understood that it has to be Hadoop compatible not Hdfs per say